# Using REMOTE_USER in IIS Rewrite Module 2.0

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'm using IIS 7.5 w/ IIS Rewrite Module 2.0 and a 3rd party authentication module. I'm trying to figure out how I can use the {REMOTE_USER} variable within my conditions in later rules, after a user gets authenticated. I can get authenticated and REMOTE_USER shows up in $_SERVER on protected pages, but IIS doesn't seem to set {REMOTE_USER} variable until after the rewrite rules get evaluated. I need to be able to use that variable within my conditions for my rewrite rules.